Bounds on relative entropy for MLE in Bernoulli coin tosses
In the context of estimating the parameter $p$ from a dataset of $n$ i.i.d Bernoulli coin tosses, we often use the relative entropy $D(p \parallel \hat{p})$ to measure the performance of an estimator $\hat{p}$.
When $\hat{p}$ is assumed to be the maximum likelihood estimator (e.g. $\hat{p} = k/n$ with $k$ being the number of heads), I am interested in the bounds of $D(p \parallel \hat{p})$ with respect to the dataset size $n$.
Indeed, the relative entropy can be infinite in certain cases (e.g., when $k=0$ and $p \in (0, 1)$), so I hope to find some bounds in the form
$
\Pr[D(p \parallel \hat{p}) \geq \varepsilon] \leq \delta.
$
I'm aware of the Sanov's theorem which states that $\Pr[D(\hat{p}\parallel p)\geq \varepsilon] \leq 2^{-n(\varepsilon-2\log(n+1)/n)}$ but I'm interested in a statement about $D(p\parallel\hat{p})$ instead of $D(\hat{p}\parallel p)$.

explain what "reversed of what I am interested in" means exactly.

The relative entropy in Sanov's is $D(\hat{p}|p)$ but I want the $D(p|\hat{p})$ instead.

one quick idea is to use multiplicative Chernoff bounds for $\hat p$ and convert those to additive bounds on $D(\hat p||p)$. Have you tried that? If you get stuck, talk to me.

I looked at Chernoff before but I'm not sure how to convert the statement about the difference $p-\hat{p}$ to $D(p|\hat{p})$. I will give it a deeper look now.

you're referring to additive Chernoff while I specifically suggested multiplicative

Obviously (except (inexplicably) not to $99%$ of mathematicians who use $\LaTeX$), the three notations $D(p||q)$ and $D(p|q)$ and $D(p\parallel q)$ look so conspicuously different from each other that you notice which one is used before seeing any of the content of the posting. But you should ignore this comment unless either you understand what I'm saying or you don't.

I'm curious, does it matter though?

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$We have
\begin{equation}
    g(\hat p):=D(\hat p\parallel p)=p\ln\frac p{\hat p}+(1-p)\ln\frac{1-p}{1-\hat p}.
\end{equation}
Take any $h\in(0,1)$. By the "multiplicative" Chernoff bound,
\begin{equation}
    P(\hat p\le(1-h)p)\le e^{-h^2 pn/2},\quad P(1-\hat p\le(1-h)(1-p))\le e^{-h^2 (1-p)n/2}. 
\end{equation}
Note that $g(p)=0=g'(p)$ and
\begin{equation}
    g''(\hat p)=\frac p{\hat p^2}+\frac{1-p}{(1-\hat p)^2}.
\end{equation}
So, on the event $\{\hat p>(1-h)p),1-\hat p>(1-h)(1-p)\}$ we have
\begin{equation}
    g''(\hat p)\le \frac1{p(1-h)^2}+\frac1{(1-p)(1-h)^2}=\frac1{p(1-p)(1-h)^2}
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
    g(\hat p)\le\frac{(\hat p-p)^2}{2p(1-p)(1-h)^2}. 
\end{equation}
So, for any real $\ep>0$ and
\begin{equation}
    \ep_1:=\frac{\sqrt\ep}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}\,(1-h)},
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
P(D(\hat p\parallel p)\ge\ep)&=P(g(\hat p)\ge\ep) \\ 
&\le e^{-h^2 pn/2}+e^{-h^2 (1-p)n/2}+P(|\hat p-p|\ge\ep_1) \\ 
&\le e^{-h^2 pn/2}+e^{-h^2 (1-p)n/2}+e^{-D(p+\ep_1\parallel p)n}+e^{-D(1-p+\ep_1\parallel 1-p)n},   
\end{align}
by the "additive" Chernoff bound, provided that $\ep$ is small enough so that $\ep_1<\min(p,1-p)$.
The latter bound on $P(D(\hat p\parallel p)\ge\ep)$ decreases exponentially in $n$.

Thanks a lot for your effort! And sorry for the late response, your answer aligns with what I needed.

Regarding the upper bound $g(\hat p)\le\frac{(\hat p-p)^2}{2p(1-p)(1-h)^2}$, I think it can also be achieved using the fact that $g$ is convex on $(0, 1)$. For convex $g$, we have that $g(p) \ge g(\hat p) + g'(\hat p)(p - \hat p)$.
